# How do I add an event to a specified google calendar using html code

Tags: html, google-calendar-api

I trying to create an html widget that allows the user to add an event to a specified google calendar. The only users who will have access to the widget are allowed to add events to the calendar, so authentication isn't a problem. The website builder I am using does not allow me to use javascript. I have scoured google and stack overflow for possible solutions to my problem, and came up with nothing.

```
<a href="http://www.google.com/calendar/event?
action=TEMPLATE
&text=[event-title]
&dates=[start-custom format='Ymd\\THi00\\Z']/[end-custom format='Ymd\\THi00\\Z']
&details=[description]
&location=[location]
&trp=false
&sprop=
&sprop=name:"
target="_blank" rel="nofollow">Add to my calendar</a>
```

This code looked the most like what I needed, but when I ran the widget and clicked on the link that the code provided, it took me to my own calendar, and didn't add an event. Is there any way at all to simply add an event using HTML?

Thanks

Comment: I don't think it's possible. As HTML, is a markup language for describing web pages not to make interactive API calls. You would need use other programming languages (i.e. JavaScript, PHP, etc.). I suggest you take a look at the Google documentation to create an [event](https://developers.google.com/google-apps/calendar/v3/reference/events/insert). Good luck!

Comment: Ok. Thanks for your help.

Answer (score -1):

This works: http://www.google.com/calendar/event?action=TEMPLATE&text=event_title&dates=yyyymmdd/yyyymmdd&details=whatever_text_in_the_description&  There are issues, though...it will honk about "cant create an event that ends before it starts" if the two dates are the same.  Apparently if you want an event all day on 3 March, you have to use 20170303/20170304 and it works.  Its squireley, may be deprecated or something.  If anyone can find documentation of this in Google, please post a link.